# Refresh component when new item selected using react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux, react-router

I'm trying to test out React functionality by creating a notes webapp.  In the left sidebar I have a list of all the notes for the currently logged in user.  When one of the notes is selected I want it to appear in the main area of the webpage.

This works the first time I select the note but not after this, unless I manually refresh the page.  I think the component mounts the first time and retrieves the note but when I select another note it's not updating the component.

I am using react-router, so when I select a note it traverses to /notes/:note_id based on the note selected.  This always changes but the content doesn't refresh.

Here is my NoteItem code:

```
var React = require('react');
var WebAPIUtils = require('../../utils/WebAPIUtils.js');
var NoteStore = require('../../stores/NoteStore.react.jsx');
var NoteActionCreators = require('../../actions/NoteActionCreators.react.jsx');
var Router = require('react-router');
var State = require('react-router').State;

var NoteItem = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ State ],

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      note: NoteStore.getNote(),
      errors: []
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    NoteStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
    NoteActionCreators.loadNote(this.getParams().noteId);
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    NoteStore.removeChangeListener(this._onChange);
  },

  _onChange: function() {
    this.setState({
      note: NoteStore.getNote(),
      errors: NoteStore.getErrors()
    });
  },

  render: function() {  
    return (
      <div className="row">
      <div className="note-title">{this.state.note.title}</div>
        <div className="note-body">{this.state.note.body}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = NoteItem;
```

And here's how I'm linking to NoteItem from my sidebar using react-router:

```
<Link to="note" params={ {noteId: this.props.note.id} }>{this.props.note.title}</Link>
```

And my routes:

```
<Route name="app" path="/" handler={NotesApp}>
  <DefaultRoute />
  <Route name="login" path="/login" handler={LoginPage}/>
  <Route name="signup" path="/signup" handler={SignupPage}/>
  <Route name="notes" path="/notes" handler={NotesSidebar}/>
  <Route name="note" path="/notes/:noteId" handler={NoteItem} />
<Route>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement [componentWillReceiveProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops), as the other livecycle methods are not called [when dynamic segments change](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/overview.md#important-note-about-dynamic-segments)